# Pivot variables in SPSS with `CASESTOVARS` and specify the resulting column names

Tags: pivot-table, spss

We regularly receive a SPSS dataset with patients, eventnames and the dates when the questionnaires were filled-in. Each record is a patient ID and an event name and a date column for each questionnaire.

We want to pivot the data to a single record per patient, with columns for each questionnaire/eventname combination with the questionnaire dates. The resulting dataset will be used to more easily see which patients need reminders or where there are missing questionnaires, so administrative staff can send reminders, close cases etc. See example datasets below (I've copied it to Excel to add colors)

[image: The original dataset]

And the desired resulting dataset:

[image: The desired resulting dataset]

Here is syntax I've got so far, with this small example dataset (the real dataset is larger and has more columns).

```
data list free /PatientId (A7) Eventname (A10) RandGroup (A10) Question1 (DATE10) Question2 (DATE10).
begin data
    PAT1001 Baseline group_II 05-03-2022 ""
    PAT1001 month3 "" "" 10-06-2022
    PAT1001 month12 "" "" 12-03-2023
    PAT2002 Baseline group_IV 22-10-2022 ""
    PAT2002 month3 "" 21-02-2023 22-02-2023
    PAT3003 Baseline group_I 29-11-2021 07-12-2021
    PAT3003 month3 "" "" 27-02-2022
    PAT3003 month12 "" 01-12-2022 03-12-2022
end data.

SORT CASES BY PatientId, Eventname.

CASESTOVARS
    /ID = PatientId
    /INDEX = EventName
    /GROUPBY = VARIABLE.
```

This syntax works, but another requirement is that we want to specify the new column names. Instead of `Question1.Baseline`, `Question2.month12` etc. we want the resulting column names to be `Q1_BASE`, `Q2_M12` etc. I know I can rename the columns manually like this:

```
rename variables (Question1.Baseline = Q1_BASE).
rename variables (Question1.month3 = Q1_M3).
rename variables (Question1.month12 = Q1_M12).
```

However in the real dataset there are a lot more questionnaire columns, and also in later datasets the questionnaire columns could have different names. So I'm looking for maybe a more systemic/futureproof way to do this

So, is there a parameter in `CASESTOVARS` to also get the desired column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much easier way to get the desired short names is to rename the variables BEFORE the `casestovars`. Also you can use the `separator` sub command to change the resulting names:

```
recode EventName ("Baseline" = "BASE")("month3" = "M3")("month12" = "M12").
rename variables (question1 to question70 = Q1 to Q70).
CASESTOVARS
    /ID = PatientId
    /INDEX = EventName
    /GROUPBY = VARIABLE
    /separator="_".
```

Comment: I can do `rename variables (question1 to question2 = Q1 to Q2).` which could also be done using the `CASESTOVARS /RENAME` parameter. However, the `rename variables (Baseline month3 month12 = BASE M3 M12)` doesn't work because those are the values not the variables, the variable name is just `Eventname`.

Comment: Sorry, you're right - see my edited response

Comment: Thanks, adding the `recode` and `rename` gets to the result I was looking for. 

Comment: Btw for anyone looking at this question at a later time, I just want to add that if the starting dataset has additional variables you want to exclude from the pivot result, you can delete them using `CASESTOVARS .. /DROP NameVariable1 NameColumn2 etc.`

Comment: Also, the `RandGroup` stays one variable in the final result, only because the original dataset happens to contain a single distinct value for each patient. As soon one patient has different RandGroup values, then it will also result in `RandGroup_BASE` `RandGroup_M3` `RandGroup_M12`.

Comment: For additional variables that do not change within an ID variable, use `fix` subcommand, so for example `/fix=RandGroup`.